# Is it good practice to force users to give us their email address before showing them our site?

Tags: e-commerce, email

Our company has a website that sells wine. Our idea is that we will the ask user to sign up using their email address before we present them with any products.

The reasoning behind this is that if a user comes to see products on our website but is not interested in anything that they find they may leave for good. However, if we add new products to our website that might be of interest to the user then if we have their email address we can advertise directly to the customers email, in the hope that they might be interested and come back to our website.

Is this a good strategy?

Comment: I, for one, will certainly *not* commit to give my email before I see what you are offering, and at what price. It feels like having to let a shopowner make a photocopy of my ID before I enter his store. In both cases, I'll just move on to the competition.

Comment: If you force them to give AN email address - then it probably won't be THEIR email address...

Comment: And what incentive do I have to give you my e-mail address if I can't see what you are offering?

Comment: I don't think I've ever bought a product online from a company that doesn't make pricing/etc information readily available.  I operate under the assumption that "If you don't want me to see it, you're assuming that I probably won't like what I see"; I see no reason not to assume the vendor is wrong in their assumption so I close the tab, and take my business to another site.

Comment: Have a read of some of the answers on [this related post about what makes people register](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18936/what-makes-users-register)

Comment: The things to hide under registration, memberships or so, should be benefits and communication advantages, but never direct offers, as this would be considered a deceiving posture. It will doubtless raise eyebrows and that's never good when you are looking for users to trust in you.

Comment: Wouldn't wine purchasers assume the stock would change often?

Comment: And also... how are search bots supposed to index your site, if they can't access your offerings?

Comment: There are a lot of web sites that sell wine, I'll just go to one of the ones which doesn't treat me so contemptuously.

Comment: @JeffO I'm not a wine purchaser, but the good wines are supposed to be old, right?  So it seems to me they'd be unlikely to change often...

Comment: Sites like that are the #1 reason for the fact that many people have two email addresses - one "real" and another for "spam".

Comment: When I come across a site like that, I just move on to a site that doesn't waste my time. Unless you want very few customers and a database full of mailinator.com addresses, ditch the idea.

Comment: You will get **many** fake email addresses. If you force me to give up information just to see your product, I will either go away or invent false information.

Comment: @Loren: I think it's because unnecessary registration is an annoyance that just about everybody has experienced, and the e-commerce vendors still haven't got the message.

Comment: This "commit before you see what we have" practice looks like something those dodgy MLM-sites or Get-Rich-Quick-EBooks would do, and would instantly drive me away. Red flag!

Comment: How are they supposed to know if they are interested or not before they know what you are offering?

Comment: `but is not interested in anything they find they will be gone forever` - What leads you to believe that?  Perhaps you should be doing a better job of communication what you may be offering in the future?  Or if your products are popular, why wouldn't the potential customer find them via a search, word-of-mouth, or some other way?   A hostile act like forcing me to provide an email to see anything is far more likely to drive me away forever.

Comment: There are lots of sites that have members-only or invitation-only services (Gilt, etc.) This can be a good model for this kind of thing, but it's a pretty limited case.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea.

You want to make purchasing from your website as easy as possible. Forcing a user to give out an email address before they're even able to see what you're selling is not a good approach. This will most probably push a big part of your customers away from the site rather than forming a commitment to it.

You should read the [$300 million dollar button](https://articles.uie.com/three_hund_million_button/), an article about a case brought to public attention by Luke Wroblewski. The article covers a case where an e-commerce site grew their revenue by 45% by making purchases easier for visitors by **Removing forced commitment between the user and the site.**

Comment: @Matt, thanks. It's a very interesting case indeed. I've used this article professionally to argue my stance on certain issues. Its figures catches the attention of most stakeholders.

Comment: Brilliant link, worth a read for any UX person who works with web

Comment: In the `$300 Million Dollar Button` story they are forcing people who have already clicked the "Take my money!" button to jump through needless hoops. Bad idea. But random visitors to the site are an entirely different story. 99% of them aren't going to buy a thing. Buying is based on trust. And one of the best ways to build trust (and remind people that your site exists) is through regular lifecycle emails to people who have given you their email address.

Comment: @pkamb Ok, so forcing a user to commit to the site before they can make a purchase instead of just offering it as an option would build trust in the user...? Gosh, what are you thinking....

Comment: Another great LW article is Sign Up Forms Must Die: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/signupforms.  It sounds like @Sarawut Positwinyu just needs a "Can't find what you're looking for?" feature.

Comment: @AndroidHustle There's nothing about the relationship that should be "forced". This wine shop would do very well, for example, by sending people a free 10-page *Expert Wine Buying Guide* in return for their email address. Their target customers (but probably not you or I) would gladly trade their email address for that. Then every week thereafter, sending a cheatsheet for buying Merlot, Cabernet, Chardonnay, etc. along with great deals on wine.

Comment: @pkamb were I to find myself forced to submit contact information before I'm allowed to even see the inventory I go to a competitor, though I might enter a fake email address first in order to throw off the site's usage statistics and get them listed on some email blacklists as well (maybe the email of the CEO of a large company...).

Comment: @jwenting Again, that's **you**. I would probably do the same myself. But you shouldn't generalize what you would do to what the target customer of the wine site would do. See my answer below (-1 points! :) for an alternative view.

Comment: @pkamb But the case that the article covers in the answer above is not you, me or jwenting. That's a case with a very wide demography, it's been hinted that the site in question is Amazon, which has a very broad target group. And in this case having forced input of email scared users off. You can argue all you want that it's not the same scenario, but that there would be any difference in a case where you don't even show content before users leave out their email I simply wont buy. I'm positive that the result would be even more catastrophic,  with an even larger drop-out.

Answer (score 90):

Usability aside, there are also some technical points against your strategy:

- Basically, you are **sending spam** to your users.
- The content of your site is hidden behind a login page - that makes it **unsearchable**. In many sites, the absolute majority of traffic comes from search results and price comparison sites (like Google Shopping).
- Similarly, the content of your site is **not linkable**. A user cannot consult with their friends, or even recommend your product, once buying it.

Comment: Spam is unsolicited email. Assuming he is not deceptive about what the emails will be used for, the users are soliciting future correspondence by registering.

Comment: @Superbest - True. There are ways around being pure spam. But still, "advertise directly to the customers email" does not sound good - most people regard that as spam. You are right though - if you are honest about it, you can get around legal issues.

Comment: It's not even legality. I imagine if the user ticks a checkbox saying, "yes, please send me periodic special offers" then they probably *want* to get the "spam". Unless you left the checkbox ticked by default, and hid it out of the way and used small type.

Comment: @Superbest - I partially disagree. In 90% of the cases where signup is required to gain access the user is **NOT** consenting to get emails, they *just* want access to the site and they were *forced* to add their email.  This is why sites like Mailinator.com are in business. ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe I agree that it's obnoxious, but that's a bit like subscribing to a magazine, and then when the bill arrives, complaining that you just wanted to read the magazine and not the subscription, isn't it? They provide a service, the price they ask is your email. Take it or leave it, "as far as they're concerned". But I do agree that the answer to the original question is "no".

Comment: I guess without clarification from the OP it might be a bit hard to judge... but my take on it was that the user didn't know they were signing up for a "service" to be notified of future releases... just that they had to provide it to gain access to existing product listings. If this were the case, I'd prefer a button/link "we don't have product XYZ, but enter your email and we'll notify you as soon as we do" would work better.  Especially if I don't want XYZ, emailing me about its arrival "becomes" spam.

Comment: @Superbest if I'm forced to give you my email in order to visit your site, then an email is sent that is spam as I didn't solicit it, I gave the email to access the site

Answer (score 38):

No. Forcing the user to enter an email address before they can view your products will more than likely drive them away, for the following reasons:

1. Increased barrier to entry to your site - resulting in a dramatic reduction of "eyes on the prize".
2. It's suspicious. The user will wonder why you're asking for their email address to just see your website.

You need to make the experience for the user as straightforward, simple and trustworthy as possible. Emails can be used for various forms of malicious behaviour, requesting them before you've earned even a smidgen of trust is not recommended.

Answer (score 38):

**(See the comments for a lively debate about this idea!)**

I disagree with the other answers here. (There are 5 at the moment.)

Like all good design answers: it depends. In 99% of cases, you'll want to put off on gathering information for as long as possible. But there are a few very good reasons you *would* want to collect information first. It all depends on your strategy.

If you're selling cheap, mass-market wines and you just want to sell to as many people as possible, then taking the information last approach is probably the way to go. Think [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/). You can do basically everything without logging in. This kind of structure works for a very general type of audience, since most people don't want to give out information right away.

However, if you're selling boutique wines to high-end clients, and you want to create a sense of elite membership, then asking for information first is pretty much required. This is how the mighty Facebook got it's start, and it's the model that sample sale sites like [Ruelala](http://www.ruelala.com/) and [Gilt](http://www.gilt.com/) rely on. (They also rely on invitations, but if that works for your customers, it can be very effective.) If your site relies on word-of-mouth to get around, you don't even need to show them anything to get them to sign up. Look into private torrent trackers like [waffles.fm](http://waffles.fm). They even try to keep things secret.

*But*, from the sound of your question, it seems like you should go the more public route. I just figured I'd throw this out there.

** EDIT: **

Some references:

Here's an article on [why invite only works](http://vator.tv/news/2008-09-15-the-power-of-the-invitation-only-effect). Here's an [interview with the founders of Gilt](http://mogultheory.com/2012/05/by-invitation-only-gilt-founder-talks-entrepreneurship-new-book/). (Read the questions from mid-page, by the book image.) Here's [a view of these sites from a user perspective](http://www.switched.com/2010/03/23/invite-only-shopping-explained-whats-good-from-gilt-groupe-to/).

The important points in my eyes are:

- Users value their membership more.
- If they have a good experience, they will want to share with others.
- You have better control over your inventory.

To me, this really boils down to the kind of customer you're after. If you want repeat customers who are looking for unique items, special discounts, high-end items, etc... then a "membership" is the route I would take. But, if you're looking for mass-market, one-off customers who are just there to get things done, then put off info gathering as long as possible.

Comment: `selling boutique wines to high-end clients` that would only work if you already had a credibility to do it, or you are confident you can build that credibility.

Comment: Absolutely. In this particular case, I'd guess that they're not going to have such a high credibility. So I'd probably suggest going the Amazon route. But who knows!

Comment: Considering throw away email addresses's are easy to come by, the "for the elite" does not work. If you want to push that, then you need to do some kind of vetting process before letting them on. For example recommended by another customer.

Comment: I like this answer, it's a good contrast to the other answers here. However I'm not totally convinced. Yes, Ruelala and Gilt may require emails before you can access the site, but how do we know that this is better for them than just having open access? It would be great if they'd published some findings stating something like *"when we switched from open-access to subscription we saw an increase of 20% in sales"* but I've not seen such data. For all we know they could be losing £1000's in potential sales by imposing such restrictions.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty I'm confused -- are you saying that my answer won't apply? Or is this just additional information?

Comment: @JonW You're totally right. I'd love to see some findings as well, but I don't think you'll find anything like that. (I've not looked though.) They could be loosing out on money by having it be restricted, but we'll never know, since there's they can't do both at the same time. All I'm trying to say is that successful businesses do operate like that. Not that they're better in any way, just that they function. Personally, I suspect that they work pretty well, if you're in the right industry, but who knows!

Comment: @LorenRogers If you want to cater for the high end market, you normally have to vet more then just an email address.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Perhaps -- but I don't remember Ruelala / Gilt asking for anything more than an email, username, password, and a referral code. I may be totally wrong though, but I don't remember it being that different from other signup forms. Do you have specific examples?

Comment: A referral code would be more then just vetting on email. The point I was making, if you plan to market yourself as a high end website you need to be able to keep the riff-raff out, and creating an email only authentication will not work due to the ease at getting throwaway email addresses.

Comment: The OP is asking whether forced relationship between a site and a customer is a good approach, and it's clearly not, this has been proven. Facebook doesn't apply, that was a matter of legal and performance issues that made entry regulated. Invite only torrent trackers want to form a regulated community with users that convey to a certain behaviour, help building the community rather than simply leaching off other users, therefore doesn't apply. Gilt and Ruelala are mentioned with no evidence of why their approach would be successful. You undermine other answers without anything to back you up

Comment: @AndroidHustle I've edited my question with some quick references / thoughts. Please provide references yourself. I'd be interested in where your perspective is coming from.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty You're right. It is certainly more than just plain username / pass. All I'm trying to point out is that there may be cases when you want to require membership of some kind before you can browse the selection. Putting an explicit membership wall up can give the impression that whatever's behind it is more valuable than if you just showed it in public. Think of a regular shop. If you had to make a reservation at a car dealer to see the models, you'd probably think they were a lot more valuable than if they just had the cars sitting in a lot.

Comment: @LorenRogers I have a reference provided in my answer.

Comment: @AndroidHustle So you do. I didn't see that you did that answer. You're right that it's been shown to be a deterring factor for major e-commerce sites, but what I'm saying is that there are cases when requiring users to register up front can work to your advantage. I'm not saying that it's nearly as 'proven' as the opposite argument, but that the idea exists. I wouldn't suggest it for the vast majority of cases, but it's an option.

Comment: @LorenRogers I understand your view also. However it wouldn't be a good idea in this case, which you're hinting as well I see. I get your "elite membership" reference, however I really don't see how that can be achieved by a user simply giving out their email address, anyone can do that, nothing elite about it. Membership from an invite, sure, but commercial businesses only accepting customers who are invited from existing customers are very few indeed. It only holds if you're selling something very exclusive to a select few, and then I don't think you do it from a website either if I'm honest

Comment: @AndroidHustle Cool. I guess I didn't state it explicitly, but I was thinking of a middle ground. Requiring a membership invite is a really good way of making your site feel exclusive, and putting registration as the last step in the shopping experience is a really good way of making your site feel inclusive. I may be totally wrong, and I have no evidence to back it up, but I suspect that by simply requiring a registration before you can browse, your site would be perceived as being more exclusive, but not too exclusive.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Actually, this is a very similar line of thought as adding a delay to a computer. I think I read about this in the book Quantifying the User Experience: the first computers needed to add some delay to their algorithms, because people thought they were computed too quickly and weren't generating the right answers. Putting a form in the way of products is totally counter-intuitive, but I suspect it adds value in much the same way. It took longer to get here, so the results must be better / more valuable. (Let me know if this made no sense...) I'll try to find that reference too.

Comment: My 2¢ on this: I have encountered multiple websites that demanded my email address before I could read their content. I responded to this by giving them a blatantly fake email, and they all accepted those fake emails. I suppose they're going to have to remove those addresses from their mailing lists at some point... but that's not my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially forcing the customer to input their email address before viewing the product can be viewed as an aggressive marketing strategy by the user. It is common that the customer, or potential customer will not like this method of marketing, and in fact have a negative vibe about the approach within itself.

Answer (score 4):

It is and is not a good practice. It depends on what you are practising and what you want to achieve.

there are two approaches/goals possible:

#### Approach 1.

**Your primary focus is to let customers see your website**
It is not to ask for any e-mail until it is really required (or user asks for it). You want your website to be seen as user friendly and your focus is on letting customers in and see.

FYI : for some users (including me) if I am browsing on a website and it is not required for me to login( I just want to browse, for that why we need login, Huh!) and the website is asking me to enter email/login/number etc. I close that website. (unless I have a very strong urge to enter or I don't have anything else to do)

You wrote that you sell wine: suppose a user is looking for a particular brand of wine. which at that moment is out of stock. So there you can have an option to ask for e-mail so you could notify the user when that wine is available.

#### Approach 2.

**Your primary focus is not to have users see your products (this is secondary), your primary focus is to fish e-mail addresses**.

You could send e-mail promotions etc, in that case its good to give a required login/enter email screen

if its case 1, then its not a good practice to give a required email dialog. if its case 2, then its a good practice.

Comment: You are basically re-iterating many of the answers already left here, however one of your points: **"Suppose a user is looking for a particular brand of wine which at that moment is out of stock."** is a very good on, so I upvote you for that point alone.

Comment: @JonW: thanks Mate, will try & make sure i don't reiterate in future

Answer (score 3):

I would ask yourself the following:

1. Approximately how many times have you bought something online in your life?
2. On how many of those occasions did you give your email address before seeing
   the product/price the website was offering? (In the figure, feel free to include websites to which you gave your email address, didn't buy anything, but returned later to buy something when they sent you promotional email.)

Comment: It's not so much about what experiences you personally have come across, but more general competitive analysis to see what your competitors are doing that is more important. It's easy to forget that you may not actually be the target audience of the product, so competitive analysis would be more appropriate. But yes, as a thought exercise then you should start with your own experiences (just don't present your experiences as *the* hard evidence)

Comment: @JonW You are entirely correct. However the other answers already explain this so I thought I'd throw a different perspective into the mix :-). It's entirely possible that the OP agrees with the answers but is asking this in a neutral fashion so as to gain ammunition for a discussion with superiors. In which case my thought excercise might be of use as something non-technical people can quickly relate to without needing to read anything. In any case: what are your answers to the two questions?

Comment: @JonW The simplest possible competitive analysis is googling for "boutique wine" and finding out whether anybody else does that. At a glance, none.

Answer (score 2):

"Is something that the majority of users hate a good UX?"

Gee, I don't know.

Look at Stack Exchange. You can start using Stack Exchange sites without creating an account. Yet, you can later create an account and the content you previously created is linked to that account. If you don't like the site, you don't have to. You have limited powers, but are able to do basic things like answer questions.

That is a good user design, which allows the system to meet its need to have registered users without throwing a bad experience at the users (requiring an up-front registration to do anything at all).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could encourage registration if you showed a few products w/o having to enter email, and then asked them after say 5 product views to enter their email for free access. It would have to be snappy, and I would not bother validating email.

Comment: Would that encourage registration though? There would be a development overhead to consider if you are going to keep track of the number of products viewed and display a registration page after 5 (or however many) views, and if its purely speculation that this would be result in significantly more registrations you may have just wasted time developing something unnecessary and / or even harmful to the sites performance. I would want to see supporting evidence that this approach works before implementing it.

Comment: I don't have any evidence. But I think it could be done. You could just interrupt after 5 views and give them the option to say "No" and continue browsing.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is tempting to use this opportunity to collect email addresses in order to access the Website, especially with a site that sells alcohol and requires some sort of age verification (...what's one more piece of data?), it is not a good idea.

Essentially, it boils down to trust.  Three things come to mind:

1) All good business practices revolve around establishing trust.  If your customers trust you, they will come back. And repeat business is crucial to success in any retail environment.  Trust is a two way street.  By requiring an email address right off the bat, you are asking your customers to give you something pretty substantial without the common courtesy of giving them something first.  There are alternatives out there for your customers... the onus is on you to initiate the relationship and establish trust.

2) With a product as diverse and capricious as wine, customers will depend on you to help them make decisions. In fact, you should want them to rely on you to help them, which would greatly increase your retention rates.  The more you can understand what they are looking for and the more you can deliver information that meets and exceeds expectations, the better off you are. Instead of asking them for an email address... ask them what they are looking for.   Red?  White?  Sparkling? Help them and then they will help you.

3) "That which grows well, grows slow." Some shortcuts end up dropping off the edge of a cliff. Take the time to develop relationships and you'll get their email address pretty quickly... as soon as they make a purchase or sign up for something else that you are offering that looks good to them (newsletter, coupons, etc.).  More importantly, by gaining their trust you may soon start to collect their friends' email addresses, and then the email addresses of their friends' friends too.

Answer (score 0):

Totally bad idea. 90% of the users will close the browser window for your website and move on to the next tab if they don't find anything useful or if the prices don't show up by default.

You must not force your users to give you their email id. In my case, I will always use https://www.guerrillamail.com/

Other than that, sending product promotion emails to users without their consent is illegal. Instead , you should focus on the users who just close the browser window when they do not find enough information ( price ) on your page.

Any new user will always hesitate to give his email address, because he does not not know how much you will be frustrating him with spam emails afterwards. He will prefer not to register. What do you think ?

If you are not sure, try experimenting with both the strategies.

Comment: *"90% of the users will close the browser window for your website and move on to the next tab if they don't find anything useful or if the prices don't show up by default."* That is quite a sweeping generalisation. Are you able to support that statement with anything?

Comment: I agree its a generalisation. The figure are not actually statistically and scientifically calculated. But transparency on the Web is the hottest and the biggest thing as far as getting people to purchase or relate to your services. If you hide something from a person who has money in his wallet, he will assume you have a gun ..

Comment: If you read this article http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button , it says that - 75% of these people never tried to complete the purchase once requested. Also the point to note is that  - " They took away the Register button. In its place, they put a Continue button with a simple message: "You do not need to create an account to make purchases on our site. Simply click Continue to proceed to checkout. To make your future purchases even faster, you can create an account during checkout.".. This is of course statistically calculated and proved

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really persuasive value proposition for your site (say, really great member perks or coupons) and can communicate that value effectively to the user, then you might be able to get away with requesting an email before the user accesses the site.

Why not consider an often used alternative to obtain emails of your most engaged users? After the user is on the site for a set period of time (or visited a certain number of pages) have a pop up that requests his or her email in exchange for additional content (could be a newsletter or extra content). That way, you will only be targeting (presumably) engaged users who are the ones that are most likely to buy your services! PopUp Domination is an example of a plugin that allows for this (I have never used it, just giving as an example).

Comment: That is a technique that gets used, but do users respond well to it? I'd like to see some data from sites that have used this to see whether or not it's a suitable option, or if it just annoys users so much they just up and leave. Is it worth risking turning off an already engaged user just to try to get their email address?

Answer (score 0):

By having a login (sign up) form before customers can even see the product is not only a barrier to those browsing or comparing prices, it is also a barrier to SEO.

How can anyone ever even find your store if it can't be indexed by Google?

How can you gain popularity enough for customers to trust you when Google doesn't?

Also, put yourself in the customers shoes. Don't answer for the sake of getting people to agree, I mean really picture the customers full buying experience.

First they have to get to your store by chance since you aren't in search engines, or they will go directly because they found your URL somewhere. They want wine obviously, but are YOU their only choice? Once that pop-up reveals itself stating, "You must provide your E-Mail address to view products."

Would you seriously go forward or look at the competitor next to you. Suppose they do click it. You say you take emails so that if they don't find what they want, you can keep them updated with new product arrivals.

But, as a customer, if I couldn't find you in the search engines, then had to give you my information, then browsed the store & you didn't have what I want, what have you given me in return?

Answer (score 0):

The main concern is that the user is not interested in anything that they find and may leave for good.

One way to find out it to use a click pattern to see if the user is really struggling to find anything and show a pop-up like below

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8cqgW.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

[You Should Probably Send More Email Than You Do](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/05/31/can-i-get-your-email/)

Please don't listen to anyone here regarding their personal email marketing preferences. They are not your customers. Geeks categorically hate email. Real people don't.

Look at the responses here. *"If **I** hit a site like that, **I'll** close the tab and move on to your competition."* Again, we are not your customers. An email splash page would probably be terrible for a specifically geek-targeted wine website. But it worked *ok* for Groupon.

So yes, you should absolutely make getting email addresses one of your top business priorities. Though not necessarily from an immediate splash screen. I really suggest reading the link I posted above for ideas. Some good quotes below:

> For example, if you’re not just publishing anonymous “content” but rather trying to reactivate users of an application (lifecycle emails) or educate-them-to-the-point-where-they-want-to-buy-something (drip marketing), a little nudge in behavior could result in adding thousands of dollars of customer LTV.

and

> Almost every first-class e-commerce company treats their house email campaigns like they are the goose that lays the golden eggs, chiefly because they are.  For companies which have repeat-purchase models, direct response to emails can represent half or more of customer lifetime value.

Comment: The crux of that article appears to be that *"if you send an email then the recipient will probably read it"*. OK, that is as may be, but how does that link in with requiring email addresses to access a website? They're already *at* the website trying to read it and you're denying them the ability to do so by requesting an email that they will *probably* read. Well if you didn't request the email address then they would *definitely* read the website content **because they are already on the site trying to do just that**.

Comment: @JonW The increased read rate is important, but it's the later half of the article you should read. Keeping prospects warm, building trust in the brand, educating them on wine, and selling directly to their inbox week after week rather than whenever the customer happens to land on their site.  

I assume this wine site is "groupon-like", because that's what everyone is building these days. Daily or weekly deals on wine. In that case especially, email lists will drive their revenue.

Comment: @JonW *They're already at the website trying to read it and you're denying them the ability to do so by requesting an email that they will probably read.*

Statistically, a single person landing on your website is very unimportant. Only 1% of them (or whatever your conversion rate is) will actually result in a sale. That's why sites require email addresses to see content; getting an email address is far more valuable than one clickthrough with *potential* to buy. This is completely different than requiring a signup *at the point of checkout*, by the way. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: You're still working on the assumption that by presenting the user with an email entry field as the first thing they see before allowing them into the site that they will actually enter their details in there, and not that they may just leave altogether because they don't want to give their details at that point. Then your 1% of site visitors equates to an even fewer number of people because you're getting less people into the site.

Comment: So how would you explain the 45% increase in revenue by removing forced commitment that is presented in my answer? This answer sure doesn't explain it, and your comments here are all based on assumptions that sound absurd.

Comment: It would be great if you could cite some references / studies to back up your answer -- I'd be interested in hearing more.

Comment: @AndroidHustle In the `$300 Million Button` story they were making it needlessly hard for people *with cash in hand* to give them money. That is of course a bad idea. But that's not really evidence that collecting an email address upfront (from people who are *not*, at that moment, throwing money at them) will result in less revenue. Groupon's implementation shows that it can be *very* profitable.

Comment: @pkamb I'm gonna be honest, I believe you're totally wrong. I understand how you think, but I don't think your assumptions are correct. I'm convinced that trading a visitors email address in exchange for them to even be able to see the site will make the absolute majority of visitors go: "pfft... I don't think so" and leave the site. In the $300 million button they had at least made a visitor keen enough to make them want to place an order, and still it scared them off! Here you have nothing, absolutely nothing up front that would appeal to the visitor. Why would they ever go along with it?

Comment: @AndroidHustle I don't necessarily think they should require an email address at the splash screen before even loading the site. That *has* worked well for many sites (Groupon, Gilt, Rue La La, etc.) but we would need to know more about the wine website before making that call. My answer serves more to offer a counterpoint to the argument that you (or at least most people here) are making: that getting a user's email address is somehow spammy/evil/worthless. If you haven't read the link I posted all the way through, I encourage you to.